# Which mass should I use to calculate torque in an Atwood machine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, torque

[image]

My question is actually about tension.

I've been wrestling with this question for a while now. While I think I mostly understand Atwood's machine, I can not understand how to answer this particular question in the way the explanation suggests.

[image]

I am confused because the explanation uses the mass of the greater mass. Why does it do that?
I was considering the tension to be the same in the system before the rope was cut and possibly the instant after the rope was cut. However, when I calculate the tension caused by both masses I get different values.

Maybe, it is the conceptual Framework I am missing.

**Why is the larger mass used for the Force/tension causing the torque?**

One last thing. My level of understanding is only at the level of algebra. Please leave out derivatives from your answers, so that I can understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says the system is initially at equilibrium. Therefore the weight on each side of the pulley must be equal. There is no large or smaller mass - the masses are equal too (presumably there are four $0.5$ kg weights on the platform to balance the $2$ kg on the other side). The tension in the rope is $T=2 \times 9.8$ N before the rope is cut, because it is supporting a $2$ kg mass *on each side*.

However, it is not clear to me why the answer assumes that after the rope is cut, there is still a tension $T$ in the rope on the left hand side of the pulley. If this were true, the platform would not start to fall.

I think the correct approach is to assume an unknown tension $T'<T$ acting on the left hand side of the pulley after the rope is cut, then establish a relationship between the downward acceleration of the platform and the angular acceleration of the pulley, and then use this relationship to solve for $T'$.

Comment: So there were 4 0.5 kg masses on the left platform, initially. I did note that the system was at equilibrium, but thought there was only one 0.5 kg on the platform. That makes sense though. However, couldn't a system of different masses be in equilibrium for an instant? In this case  I can calculate and prove the tension is the same throughout the system, once I find the magnitude and direction of the predicted acceleration.

Comment: @Haley Yes. This isn’t stated explicitly in the question, but to achieve equilibrium in the absence of friction, I think this must be the case.

Comment: Could a system of different masses be in equilibrium for an instant? If yes, then I can calculate and prove the tension is the same throughout the system, once I find the magnitude and direction of the predicted acceleration.

Comment: @Haley Not with different masses on each side, no. If the masses on each side were changing, then the system could momentarily be in equilibrium at an instant when the masses on each side happened to be equal. But this isn't the case here. The phrase "initially at equilibrium" means that the system is in equilibrium right up until when  the string is cut,

Comment: Alright. Thank you.